# Is it possible to access variables without putting "global" in front of them in functions?

Tags: php

My code is much more complex than this, but here's the just of it:

```
$string = "wuddup";

function echothis() {
echo $string;
}

echothis();
```

Is there an easy way to do this without saying `global $string`?

Reason being, I have a check login function, with many variables and I have config variables outside the function...

Comment: If you can refactor your global variables into different groups, you can wrap them in object named `$login`, `$config`, etc... and pass them to functions, instead of passing 20 different variables.

Comment: Objects are the things that look like: $login->username?

Comment: I've been out of touch with php syntax for a while. But here it goes: Instance's properties can be accessed like you said `$login->username`, and static properties can be accessed like `login::username`. The static way to do it, like in Vinod's answer should work fine for you. You end up passing just one or two objects and access their properties inside.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever happened to parameters?

```
function echothis($str) {
    echo $str;
}

echothis($string);
```

If you are having issues with managing variables and their scope, chances are you need to refactor your code structure.

Comment: Like I said, passing tons of variables in, I want a super easy way. like possibly a different type of function?

Comment: @swag31 you can look into [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) or refactor your code structure to not rely on so many variables.

Comment: This I think is going to be the option I go with, and use square bracket syntax.

Comment: Note that that syntax is only supported in PHP versions >= 5.4; You can mark this as the answer and be on your way :)

Comment: Can I access objects from inside functions? Also, I know my php supports it as I use it a lot.

Comment: Yes, they are just another variable.

Comment: Would I need to pass an object in as a parameter? What's more effective at passing in many values, an array or object

Comment: The object is still a variable, so you can use `global` like you stated in your question, or parameters. Arrays have less overhead than objects but the difference isn't noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Just Create a class and add static variables to it. You can access it from any where without creating an instance of the class.

```
class base2 {
public static $var2 = 1;
```

}

Refer it as below

```
echo base2::$var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have your function take in the variables as arguments or perhaps an array containing all these arguments.

```
$all_variables = array(
  "string" => "wuddup",
  "number" => 6,
  "an_array" => array(1, 3, 4)
);

function example_func($args) {
  // does things
}

example_func($all_variables);
```

Alternatively, you could create a class and reference the variables through `$this`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define config variables as constants and call them inside the function.